# Why is "Chop Gate" pronounced so strangely?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, toponyms

I was passing through the hamlet of Chop Gate (in North Yorkshire) the other day, and heard it referred to as "chop yat" (tʃɒp yæt). This source [here](http://www.hintsandthings.com/library/Place-name-pronunciation.htm) concurs with that pronunciation.

Does anyone know why it is pronounced in that way (or, alternatively, why it is spelt that way)?

Comment: Interesting question (I gave you +1)... Is there an audio available to hear it? First thing that comes to my mind could be the last remnants of some old pronunciation?

Comment: @Alenanno, not so far as I know. I've done the best I can with spelling and IPA, but really it needs to be spoken with a Yorkshire accent.

Comment: Is that /tʃɒp yæt/ or /tʃɒp jæt/?  /tʃɒp yæt/ (loosely, chahp ee-at) would be very strange for that spelling.

Comment: @Charles, I pinched the y from yacht, here... http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yacht which has it \ˈyät\. But Collins has it as /jɒt/. So I have to say, I'm confused. But y as in yacht, yellow, year, is what I meant.

Comment: M-W is respelling and Collins is using IPA.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It may be because the *g* in Old English could be pronounced like a *y* when followed by an *e* or *ea* diphthong. For example, *middangeard*, the term used to refer to "this place right here where people live" (literally "middle earth" — so you can see where Tolkien got the term) was pronounced *middahnyaird*. The North Yorkshire accent may retain some vestiges of Old English pronunciation.

Comment: He really took the term from that? Very interesting!

Comment: Actually, *geard* in the OE is 'literally' an *enclosure*, which survives in some dialects as *garth* but elsewhere evolves into ModE *yard*. It was not until *middangeard* passed into ME that it was 'folk-etymologized' into middle *earth*

Answer (score 8):

Maps aren't written by locals.

For example "Pately Bridge" is known locally as  "Pately Brig".  Brig being norse for a large rock outcrop - no bridge involved. But some map maker came from the south, asked a local what the place was called and misunderstood the answer.

It's not that "gate" is necessarily pronounced 'yat' - the 'yat' pronunciation is possibly from some totally unrelated earlier word and "gate" is the nearest the official surveyor could come to it (edit apparently in this case yat = gate)

Yorkshire has a wide variety of place names, from early celtic (Pen-y-ghent), mostly Norse, a few anglo-saxon and a scattering of modern Norman places.

Comment: There's a place in Derbyshire called Cowers Lane, which is said to be the mapmaker's interpretation of Cowhouse Lane (Cow 'us in the local dialect).

Answer (score 3):

Chop Gate is pronounced Chop Yat. It is Old Norse for Pedlar's Way with the "Yat" being an old Norse word for route or gate.

Comment: and if you had a reference, this could be the best answer.